# DISTINCT results in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

What i need is to retrieve the uid that does not have zip 17 in his list.

```
-------------
uid | zipcode
-------------
2   |   17
2   |   30
7   |   18
7   |   17
9   |   20

SELECT uid, zip FROM nt_shipping WHERE zip != 17 GROUP BY uid;
```

does not work. i need to bundle the zips for every customer and then use another query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get a list of all uids that have zip = 17 through a select statement. Then pick all uids in the table `nt_select` that are not in the previous select statement.

```
SELECT uid, GROUP_CONCAT(zip) all_zips
FROM nt_select 
WHERE 
uid NOT IN (SELECT 
            uid 
            FROM
            nt_shipping 
            WHERE zip = 17 GROUP BY 1)
GROUP BY 1
```